# How to replace certificate in Exchange 2010 with one that's been reissued with an additional SAN?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a "Standard UCC SSL Certificate" from GoDaddy. I needed to add another SAN to it. They were able to reissue without having to create and submit a new CSR. However, I am now having trouble getting Exchange to recognize it. I went through the wizard for "Import Exchange Certificate" in the Server Configuration, and it said it was successful, but the new cert does not show up in the list. I tried doing it again, and was told that a certificate with that thumbprint already exists. So it's apparently there, but I seem to be missing a step before it will let me use it. I've searched for help, but everything I've found is about renewing the certificate or installing the initial one.

Comment: The way windows bind public/private key pairs it would be easier for you to re-key the certificate with the new SANs.  Very easy to do with Godady and well documented for exchange.

Comment: Would it be best to treat this as a renewal on the Exchange side, or create a new one?

Comment: never renew,  always make new keypairs.